# How to call a smart contract function in a DAPP?

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development, react

I am trying to make a DAPP.

I followed this link -

https://medium.com/@takleakshar/how-to-build-a-decentralized-full-stack-app-in-ethereum-and-react-42e63d45a208

This is how my 'Setup.js' looks.

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

const marketplaceContract = new web3.eth.Contract( ABI , 'Smart 
Contract Address', {
from: '0x123....', // default from address
gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this 
case
});

//const marketplaceContract = 
web3.eth.contract(MarketABI).at(MarketAddress);
export { marketplaceContract };
```

As you can see, I am importing the smart contract with the name 'marketplaceContract'.

When I call a function from the smart contract using-

```
marketplaceContract.addGoods(name, user, age, brand, size, sp);
```

I get the output as

```
TypeError: _Setup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.marketplaceContract.addAccounts is not a function
```

Although, addAccounts is a function.

**I don't know if this is a problem with the version of web3. Please kindly help. Is there any other way to call the functions in my React-JS file?**

PS - I don't know if I have to put the whole code here. If required, please tell me, I will put both the smart contract and the React file here. I didn't put it because it's very big. 
Please don't start scorning me.

**EDITS**

When I have a `.call()` function, it works well. But when I have a function that stores some data in a struct datatype in the Blockchain, it does not work. 
I used `.send({from: accounts[0]})` for that function. Then the error pops up

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**

I searched for this error. I deleted my package-lock.json file and node_modules and then did npm install.
Still, I get the same error.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id10 . You have to add .methods to your contract instance and then call the smart contract method.

Comment: When I am using it for `.call()`, it's working absolutely fine. Then, I used `.send()`. I get the error as    **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: You can read the difference between .call() and .send() here - https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call and https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send . Basically .call() is used in web3 to call constant methods and transaction creation is not needed (you don't have to sign anything with your private key and you won't be charged eth fee) meanwhile .send() is used when you want to change contract state (you have to create transaction and sign it with your private key).

Comment: Thanks Miroslav. I read that up. I had to change some state in the smart contract but send() wasn't working because of `truffle console`. But, now it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
getMinABI: function () {
    return [
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [{"name": "_owner", "type": "address"}],
            "name": "balanceOf",
            "outputs": [{"name": "balance", "type": "uint256"}],
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "decimals",
            "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "uint8"}],
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [{"name": "_to", "type": "address"}, {"name": "_value", "type": "uint256"}],
            "name": "transfer",
            "outputs": [{"name": "success", "type": "bool"}],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ];
}

let contract = new Web3.eth.Contract(this.getMinABI(), 'contract address', {
     from: 'your address'
});

contract.methods.balanceOf('your address').call().then((balance) => {
   console.log(balance)
});
```

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the EDIT part:

There's some issue with `truffle console`. If you call the function with `truffle console` running, then you will get the same error. Recompile and again migrate the smart contract. Run the DAPP again using `npm start`.

There we go. Everything runs smoothly.